# sqlbulkcopy error inserting into 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

Hi I'm trying to save the details of an xml file into two tables. The insert was able to run sucessfully on the first table but when it reaches the second table I get an error message "ArgumentNullException was unhandled: Value cannot be null.". I'd even made sure my tables allow null but I still am getting the error. Below is my code.

```
 private void btnStore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string cs = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WangSCM;integrated security=true;";
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                // load the xml file
                XmlDocument invDoc = new XmlDocument();
                ds.ReadXml(selectedFile);

                DataTable sourceData = ds.Tables["Invoice"];
                DataTable sourceData2 = ds.Tables["InvoiceItem"];


                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlbc = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlbc.DestinationTableName = "Invoice";
                    sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("invoiceID", "invoiceID");
                    sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("invoiceDate", "invoiceDate");
                    sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("orderID", "orderID");
                    sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("sellerID", "sellerID");
                    sqlbc.WriteToServer(sourceData);
                }

                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlbc2 = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlbc2.DestinationTableName = "InvoiceItem";
                    sqlbc2.ColumnMappings.Add("invoiceID", "invoiceID");
                    sqlbc2.ColumnMappings.Add("description", "description");
                    sqlbc2.ColumnMappings.Add("quantities", "quantity");
                    sqlbc2.ColumnMappings.Add("totalcost", "totalPrice");
                    sqlbc2.WriteToServer(sourceData2);
                }

                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InvoiceData xmlns="http://assignment2.com">
<invoice InvoiceID="1">
<invoicedate>9 May 2015</invoicedate>
<SellerID>001</SellerID>
<BuyerID>001</BuyerID>
<OrderID>001</OrderID>
<ItemID>123</ItemID>
<itemname>CPU</itemname>
<description>This is a central processing unit.</description>
<quantities>50</quantities>
<totalcost>$5000</totalcost>
 </invoice>
</InvoiceData>
```

Why am i getting this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you double check on your table schema and the corresponding values that you are passing ? This seems to be an issue of passing a null value into a non-nullable column.

Comment: @HarveySpecter i've just checked again, they're all null-->

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceItem](
 [invoiceID] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [productID] [varchar](16) NULL,
 [description] [varchar](255) NULL,
 [capacity] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [quantity] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [unitPrice] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [totalPrice] [varchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: I cant see the columns `quantities` and `totalcost` in the script that you mentioned. Double check on the columns if they exist and are proper.

Comment: @HarveySpecter the 'quantities' and 'totalcost' are from the xml file that i am supposed to save the data from, i've just added the xml above. just to be sure, i had even commented out 'totalcost' and 'quantities' from the sqlbulkcopy code but still receive the error. i'm getting clueless

Comment: At which point are you getting the exception in your code ?